# set checked checkboxes like in ms excel by mouse dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-plugins

Hi i make list by php nearly 500~ value in a table
(Sil = Delete)

[image: table]

i already use jquery for my project

is there any plugin that allows you make checked multiple checkbox in jquery if they move the mouse on 2 parent div while mouse left button is on clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, like this:

var mouseIsDown;

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function() {    
    mouseIsDown = true;
});

$(document).on('mouseup', function() {
    mouseIsDown = false;
});

$('td').on('mouseenter', function() {        
    if(mouseIsDown) {
        $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

See the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nuKEK/

Comment: Whoop, that was debug code, I removed it :) But yeah, it will appear if you have a browser JavaScript console opened, or Firebug.

Comment: if its check tries to check again it must uncheck :) ?

Comment: That is [easily fixable](http://jsfiddle.net/nuKEK/1/), but the failure to check/uncheck the starting checkbox isn't.

Comment: is it possible to to do without make a new variable like ch can't we do it by using this *just wondering*

Answer (score 0):

yes it is fairly easy! And already closely answered on another topic here on SO.

To get an idea, hence the following simple code below.

PS: This is taken from
[mouseover while mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970973/mouseover-while-mousedown)

You only have to replace the .node wit ha class your checkboxes have in common, and instead of setting css you have to toggle (or check) your selector (i.e: your checkbox)

Enjoy... :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var isDown = false;   // Tracks status of mouse button

  $(document).mousedown(function() {
    isDown = true;      // When mouse goes down, set isDown to true
  })
  .mouseup(function() {
    isDown = false;    // When mouse goes up, set isDown to false
  });

  $(".node").mouseover(function(){
    if(isDown) {        // Only change css if mouse is down
       $(this).css({background:"#333333"});
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit:**

To check/uncheck a checkbox you may use

```
$('.myCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
```