# Mouseover gets fired without mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some textboxes. I want to change their border-color to black on mouseover after mousedown. But when I mousedown and select the outer area from cells then mouseover fires without firing mousedown.

[Here is a fiddle of the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/salok/v4btgen2/2/) and here is my javascript:

```
var _mouseDown = false;

$( "input[id^='text']" ).mousedown(function() {
    _mouseDown = true;
});
$( "input[id^='text']" ).mousemove(function() {
    if ( _mouseDown ) {
        $(this).css("border-color","black")
    } 
});
$( "input[id^='text']" ).mouseup(function() {
    _mouseDown = false;
});
```

Comment: Why do you wrote it's urgent ? Nothing is urgent...

Comment: Boss this is going to closed!!! Mouseover is always first event when you move your pointer on any DOM node.

Comment: try this  http://jsfiddle.net/v4btgen2/3/

Comment: @AlokSharma why don't you take a look at `focus` event.

Comment: Ya that's right but my quesion is After mousedown , mouseover works but not mouseout event.  If i select cells outside their area with mousedown , it starts mouseovering without mousedown next time

Comment: possible duplicate of [mouseover while mousedown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970973/mouseover-while-mousedown)

Answer (score 0):

**[Reference, this will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970973/mouseover-while-mousedown)**

Try this one

```
var _mouseDown = false;
$( document ).mousedown(function() {
    _mouseDown = true;
});
$( "input[id^='text']" ).mousemove(function() {
    if ( _mouseDown ) {
        $(this).css("border-color","black");
    } 
});
$( document ).mouseup(function() {
    _mouseDown = false;
});
```

Here is the sample [**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/foqoyafixu/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank u Naveen , it resolved my issue . i was using input id in mouse up function instead of document due to which cells used to get selected as black border color on mouseover without mousedown